# Uniform convergence implies limit function is in $L^1.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I have the following problem. Let $M>0$, and consider the sequence $(p_n)$ of real valued functions in $L^1([-M,M], \mathcal{B}[-M,M], \mu)$.  Suppose that $(p_n)$ converges uniformly to some $f: [-M,M] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I need to show that $f$ is integrable. I thought of using the dominated convergence theorem, but I could not find a dominating $L^1$ function. Help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Choose $n_0$ such that $|f-p_{n_0}|<1$ on $[-M,M].$ Use the triangle inequality to estimate $|f|$ in terms of $|p_{n_0}|.$

Comment: I assume that you mean with $f_n$ the sequence of measurable functions converging to $f$?

Comment: Right, I'll fix that.

Comment: I don't understand how I can use this

Comment: You're going to smack your forehead if I say more. Think about it.

Comment: Am I still looking for an $L^1$ function that bounds $|p_n|$ for all $n$?

Comment: OK, here you go: $|f|\le |f-p_{n_0}| + |p_{n_0}| < 1 + |p_{n_0}|$

Comment: I got that already :0 , but I do not know how to proceed

Comment: So $|f|$ is smaller than the sum of two $L^1$ functions, namely $|p_{n_0}|$ and $1.$

Comment: And what does this tell about $|p_n|$?

Comment: That's not the right question. The right question is what does this tell you about $f.$ We have shown $|f|<1 + |p_{n_0}|\in L^1$ Therefore $f\in L^1.$